# Error 3464 When adding REPLACE function

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error, sqldatatypes

For some reason which neither myself or our SQL expert can figure out is why adding a **REPLACE** function to this code gives me the following: 
**Error 3464 Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression** 
I am pulling this data in from an ODBC connecting our external measurement software (LIMS database) into a statistical charting software called NWA (North West Analytics) using a user-defined SQL as follows:

```
    TRANSFORM Max([NRESULT]) 
    SELECT  [DATE_SUBMITTED], [COMMINGLED_LOT], [METHOD_SUBCLASS], [MKT_SYNONYM], [CONTAINER_NO], 
           REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([CONTAINER_NO], " ",""),"-",""),"_","") AS [CONTAINER_NO_FIXED],
    FROM [dbo.V_NWA_RESULT]        
    WHERE [MKT_SYNONYM]="64860" AND [METHOD_SUBCLASS] IN ("Raw Lot", "RAW 
    LOT") AND [DATE_SUBMITTED]>=DATE () - 360           
    GROUP BY [DATE_SUBMITTED], [COMMINGLED_LOT], [METHOD_SUBCLASS], 
    [MKT_SYNONYM], [CONTAINER_NO]
    PIVOT [PA_NAME]  IN   ("Aluminum (Al)",    "Antimony 
    (Sb)",      "Arsenic (As)",       "Barium (Ba)")
```

When we used the **REPLACE** function on one of our data sets which is almost identical to this nothing fails. Do I need to use some type of REGENEX function or is it my syntax (i.e. do I need to bracket the `_` char since it is considered a ? The main goal is to remove the `-` and `_` characters from the [CONTAINER_NO] field which contains alpha-numeric data for example:

### **Container No**

---

T164  - *This is what I want the data in [CONTAINER_NO_FIXED] to look like*

---

T-164 - The "-" & space b/t & "_" chars are the ones I would like to remove

---

T 164

---

G3

---

G_3

---

T_149

---

T149

Any help I am at a loss!!!

Comment: You've tagged this MySQL, but that syntax isn't MySQL. It doesn't have TRANSFORM or PIVOT. What database product are you using?  MS Access?

Comment: I have attempted to change the tags of this question. @hunterbox, please correct the tags if needed. Choosing accurate tags is important because experts on Stack Overflow follow certain tags and so if you tag correctly, you have a better chance of attracting the attention of the person best able to give you an answer.

Comment: The mysql tag is unfortunately automatically suggested: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275170/stop-generic-database-questions-from-getting-mysql-as-a-suggested-tag  @BillKarwin

Comment: If you remove TRANSFORM and PIVOT, does the base query work?

Comment: @Bill Karwin, I apologize I guess it is just SQL, but the transform and pivot statements are used to denormalize our data. If I take them out the query does not work which is why I am so puzzled since the code works on an almost identical data set (pulling N instead of O result which basically gets rid of all negative values and truncates them to our reporting limit). MS Access is the DB